# is there any way to find queue manger name from just Channel name?

Tags: ibm-mq

I know if you have the Queue manager name, you can use it to display channels defined for it. but can you do the other way around and find out what Queue manager a channel belongs to?

Answer (score 0):

Multiple queue managers can have the same channel name, for example the sample SYSTEM.DEF.SVRCONN.
So from this you cannot tell the name of your queue manager.
You could have MYCHANNEL_QMA, and know from your naming conventions that this is for QMA, but this could also exist on queue manager QMB.

Using platform commands, you may be able to get the IP address of the remote end, and so find the machine it is running on.  From IP address and port, you may be able to pin it down, but there is a good chance you cannot get this information as you may not have access to the information on the box.

It might be easier for your application to use MQINQ on the connection and display this.

Colin